# layout_below not working with layout_centerVertical

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have been trying to use RelativeLayout in ScrollView to positioning two LinearLayouts, one to top and one to center. I've used layout_alignParentTop and layout_centerVertical. To prevent overlapping I've tried to use layout_below on second LinearLayout but it breaks layout_centerVertical and the second LinearLayout goes to top. How to do it? Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".activities.StartFragment">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/trial_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/trial_border"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trial_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:text="@string/trial_exp"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trial_more"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="right|center"
                    android:text="@string/trial_exp_more"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkGreen"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/trial_button"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/VImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="200sp"
                    android:src="@drawable/image_global" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/VText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/protection_disabled"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkRed"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/start_vpn_button"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="141dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/protect_me"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/green" />

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/stop_vpn_button"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="141dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/unprotect_me"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/red" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/r_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/single_border"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/r_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/image_r_50" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:text="@string/r_to"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You can't have layout below and layout_centerVertical.  Both of them fix the top border of the view.  You can only have 1 thing fix the top border-  using two makes the app choose which one to listen to.  Below means directly below-  not somewhere below but it doesn't matter where.

Comment: And how can I prevent overlapping when use layout_alignParentTop and layout_centerVertical?

Comment: You can put a layout_above on the view above, to prevent overlap.  But you need to think out what you want to happen there.  In that case, if there was overlap the overlapping views would just not appear from the top linear layout.  I'm not sure that's what you want.  You need to actually think that through